# Jest test to see if *.spec.tsx files exist

Tags: jestjs, tsx

I have a TypeScript project that contains a bunch of files in different directories all located under src/.

Is it possible to write a Jest test so that it only returns success if each *.tsx file found under the parent directory (src/) has a corresponding *.spec.tsx test file?

In other words if I have the following 3 files:

```
src/index.tsx
src/foo.tsx
src/folder/component.tsx
```

The Jest test would fail until such time that the following files are created:

```
src/index.spec.tsx
src/foo.spec.tsx
src/folder/component.spec.tsx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using

```
import fs from 'fs';
```

and then using `fs.readdir` and `fs.statSync` to determine if a file is a file or a directory so that I can recursively look in every location from my `src/` path.

Comment: This is not going to create a dependency for fs in the tests?